# Excel VBA find column number of user selected range (by mouse)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that allows a user to select a column with their mouse.  Then, the user selects whether or not that column has a Header.  How can I define the column number of the range that is selected so that I can perform functions on it like:

```
usc = rng.columns

For i = 2 to lastrow

cells(i,usc + 1).Value = left(Cells(i,usc),2)

next i
```

The script I have is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select your target column. "     & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                Title:="Select Column", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    hdr = MsgBox("Does your selection contain a header?", vbYesNo +     vbQuestion, "Header Option")
```

Comment: `Selection.Rows.Row` gives the number of the selected cell's row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test()
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Please select your target column. " & Chr(10) & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", "Select Column", , , , , , 8)

MsgBox "Selected column is: " & Rng.Column & Chr(10) & "Selected row is: " & Rng.Row

End Sub
```

result

[image]